# This code gives you tomorrow after midday

Tags: vba

Consider this:

```
Dim n as Long
n = Now
```

Why does this give you tomorrow after midday?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because Now returns a double to represent the time of day as well as the day itself. The fractional part is used to model the time of day and at noon that value is exactly one half.

Also, the implicit cast to Long rounds the value. This is unlike the casts of c and c++ which truncate the fractional part.

You could use Fix(Now) to truncate.

Comment: Not at all: it's one of the more unexpected corners of VBA.